# Click item on hover menu with Selenium webdriverusing python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

why I cant capture this element using 
**driver.find_element_by_link_text("Trading Data")**

[Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wafNA.png)

Comment: Please include the html fragment in your question rather than an image of the html.

Comment: The likely issue is that there's more than just text inside the A tag here. Many times that introduces extra whitespace to where an exact match doesn't work. There are several workarounds one being switch to `.find_element_by_partial_link_text()`. If there are still collisions with other elements, you'll have to have to find another type of locator that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using an xpath instead, because it seems that CSESectorSummery is a unique part of that link. Try this instead:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@ui-sref='CSESectorSummery']");
```

put an @ in front of ui-sref

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[ui-sref='CSESectorSummery']"}

Comment: the **link_by_text** is used to get <a> tags why its not working here ?

Comment: my apologies, put an @ in front of ui-sref. "//a[@ui-sref='CSESectorSummery']"

Comment: Try that and we can move forward from there.

Comment: it worked. thank you Jonah, why  **link_by_text** didn't  return any results ?

Comment: If it worked please accept my answer with the checkbox under the score so the question can be closed with an accepted answer. I wonder if link_by_text didn't work because there is a link further up in the dom with the same text.